# Gradle strange multi-project structure on IntelliJ Idea's gradle view

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I have a gradle multi-project environment structured like this:

```
- root
    - a
    - b
    - c
    - utils
```

`root`'s `settings.gradle` file is mostly this:

```
include ':a', ':b', ':c', ':utils'
```

`a`, `b`, `c` have a dependency on `utils`.

I'm using intellij-idea as IDE. The problem is that on the `gradle` view the structure it shows is

```
- root
    - :utils
    - root
- a
    - :a (root)
    - :b
    - :c
    - :utils
    - :root
... //the same for b, c and utils
```

I'm not sure this is a real issue itself, but I suppose that it might cause some slowness in project building.

Moreover, there's another issue that is more troubling: in every subproject's module's `build.gradle` file I'm using a function that I've defined in `root`'s `build.gradle`. This function adds a task. The problem is that the task is added to every node `root` child of `a`,`b`,`c` or `utils` but not to the `root` root node.

```
//hypothetical extract from a's build.gradle
...
task addTask {
    foo(project, ['param1','param2'])
}

//root's build.gradle
ext.foo = { Project prj, List<String> params ->
    params.each {
        p -> task "addedTask-${p}"() {
            println 'hello'
        }
    }
}
```

I suppose that there is a heavy configuration problem in my project's configuration but I really don't know where to start looking for it.

Comment: Why do you think there configuration problem? Are there any problems with the project build? You can use "gradle -q dependencies" command line to inspect the dependencies for the Gradle source sets: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/inspecting_dependencies.html

Comment: @Andrey it's just a sensation, the only issue I can measure is that the task is added to every node root child of a,b,c or utils but not to the root root node.